# Were Luke and Leia aware they had the same birthday?

Tags: star-wars, luke-skywalker, princess-leia

In both Legends and current canon, Luke and Leia had been told at least some true information about their origins while growing up:

- Luke knew that Owen and Beru were his aunt and uncle, and that his father's name was Anakin Skywalker, although he was told that his father had died and was a "navigator on a spice freighter".
- Leia knew that Bail and Breha were her adoptive parents, as evidenced by Luke asking if she remembers her "real mother" in *Return of the Jedi*.

However, they don't seem to have had any suspicion that they might be related until *Return of the Jedi*, even though they were born on the same day of the same year and both knew they were both adopted under mysterious circumstances. Even if the Rebel military didn't celebrate birthdays, Leia would presumably have access to everyone's personnel file as a Rebel officer. This raises the question of whether they knew the real day (or location) of their birth, or whether their adoptive guardians told them something else.

**Did Luke or Leia know when (or where) they were born?** Answers from canon and Legends are both acceptable.

Comment: If you were adopted and met someone who was cared for by their aunt and uncle (so not the "same level" of adoption) and they were from Outer Mongolia and you were from Paraguay and you happened to have the same birthday, you would go "Wow this is a huge coincidence".   You wouldn't jump to "We must be siblings."

Comment: Also, Obi-Wan and Yoda were kind of busy at the time.   Do you think the top of their list was to take note of the date and make sure they communicated it to the Berus and the Organas?

Comment: When they shared birthday cards it probably came up - but surely people living in the Star Wars galaxy know about the "Birthday Problem": https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_problem

Comment: Do we even have any evidence that they would have used the same calendar to keep track of their birthdays? For certain they weren't counting time relative to the Battle of Yavin in 19 BBY. And it seems unlikely that Tatooine was using whatever the standard galactic calendar was before then.

Comment: @ThePhoton - Everyone in SW uses the Coruscanti calendar

Comment: @Valorum, "Historians" reviewing events after the fact do. People on a distant Hutt-dominated world with only tenuous connections to the empire?

Comment: @ThePhoton - Apparently everyone does. Note that the majority of people who live there are colonists from the inner planets who traveled there on the [Dowager Queen](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Dowager_Queen) so there's ample connection with Coruscant

Comment: @Valorum, in Wikia there's an entry for the [Great ReSynchronization](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Great_ReSynchronization) (what level canon it is, IDK) which says "The Great ReSynchronization was a 60-year-long notation system that was established in 36 BBY by the Republic Measures & Standards Bureau to recalibrate the **disparate dating systems** used by the Galactic Republic." [emphasis added] In the real world it took 100's of years for calendrical reform (Gregorian to Julian calendar) to take hold across Europe.

Comment: Even if there was officially one calendar for the whole Republic or Empire, it's preposterous to think it was actually used universally in every day life across the galaxy.

Comment: @ThePhoton - You have to remember that this is a universe where interstellar travel has existed for hundreds of generations.

Comment: @Valorum, and yet where communication between planets is basically at the level of communication between countries in the age of sail on Earth.

Comment: @ThePhoton - We don't really know what interconnection there is between planets. We know that many of them share embassies, trade deals, etc

Comment: @ThePopMachine Definitely - even in a setting with as many implausible coincidences as Star Wars, having the same birthday as someone wouldn't be proof of anything. I'm more just curious if it's ever come up in any official works.

Comment: Oh, it also occurs to me:   You are statistically LESS likely to be the sibling of someone who has the exact same birthday than someone who doesn't....

Comment: @Valorum IIRC I read somewhere the mention of 10.000 generations - either for the existence of the old republic or for the time span the Jedi watched over OR. It was most likely in a novelization of one of the original trilogy movies, although I can't completely outrule the possibility that it was in one of the earlier EU-novels (like Thrawn-trilogy or X-wing novels).

Comment: @VolkerLandgraf Obi-Wan refers to the Jedi and the Old Republic co-existing for "over a thousand generations" in ANH, maybe that's what you're thinking of?

Comment: Agreeing with @Valorum: A unified timekeeping system is probably essential to a unified navigational system, if you want to calculate your hyperspace vectors based on navigational charts that tell you where the stars are supposed to e.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the *Leia Princess of Alderaan* book by Claudia Gray, it says that Leia did not know the exact day of her birth but that they just went by when Bail brought her home to Breaha; and you learn in the *Revenge of the Sith* book that Bail, Yoda and Obi Wan watch Padme's funeral so we can assume that it's not the same day.

Answer (score 11):

In the Canon biography *Skywalker: A Family at War*, it's established that Leia had a false birthday:

> Within days of Padmé Amidala's death, the newborn was adopted into the Royal House of Alderaan, and presented soon after to the people during a Name Day ceremony. Her birth was officially recorded as taking place several months earlier, to avoid any potential suspicions.
>
> (page 121)

Based on this, it's unlikely that Leia knew her real date of birth.

Comment: A very nice (canon) find

Comment: Although it does say something about the observational skills of the average Alderaan resident that they can't tell the difference between a baby several days old and one several months old. This might explain Bail's confidence he could pull it off, because he knew his people.